# Action when youtube video is ended!

Tags: php, javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I have a database with the youtube ID's.
Now i want to play the first video and when the video is ended i want to go to
http://www.foo.com/index.php?play=1 . So it will play the next youtube video. After that video is done it will go to http://www.foo.com/index.php?play=2 ... . I have tried something with the time to refresh page after x (x is duration of video) seconds. But when the user hit the pause button it will refresh to early.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You'd need to find a youtube capable player that can be interfaced to using javascript, and also fires events upon video completion. Then you could use an AJAX call to get the next video's URL and pass it to the player.

Comment: Have a look at the YouTube JavaScript Player API, it should have everything you need. http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could use YouTube JavaScript API Player. This player will fire events such as playback ended, playback paused and video cued. You can hook a function inside the playback ended event. Have a look at [YouTube JavaScript Player API Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html) and scroll down to the [events](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#Events) section.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION** (worked within my wordpress site): Download & install this to your site - http://www.tikku.com/jquery-youtube-tubeplayer-plugin

**then insert this code in your page** 
*but change

1) **yoursite.com** to yours

2) **alert("Hello");** to your desired function;

3) **DkoeNLuMbcI** to your video id;*

```
<div id="youtube-player-container" style="float:right"> </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yoursite.com/folder/jQuery.tubeplayer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#youtube-player-container").tubeplayer({
    width: 422, // the width of the player
    height: 285, // the height of the player
    allowFullScreen: "true", // true by default, allow user to go full screen
    initialVideo: "DkoeNLuMbcI?autoplay=1", // the video that is loaded into the player
    preferredQuality: "default",// preferred quality: default, small, medium, large, hd720
    onPlay: function(id){}, // after the play method is called
    onPause: function(){}, // after the pause method is called
    onStop: function(){}, // after the player is stopped
    onSeek: function(time){}, // after the video has been seeked to a defined point
    onMute: function(){}, // after the player is muted
    onPlayerEnded: function(){ alert("Hello"); },
    onUnMute: function(){} // after the player is unmuted
});
</script>
```